# Understanding scope correctly in PHP (versus Javascript)

Tags: php, function, scope, global-variables

I know that scope works differently in PHP and in Javascript.

When I first started learning Javascript (after a couple of years learning PHP), I did not initially realise that variables declared outside a function were also accessible from *inside* the function.

Now (after a few years of focusing much more on Javascript), I am stumped by how to return a PHP function-scope variable back to the extra-function environment.

**Example:**

```
$myArray = array();

function addItemsToMyArray($myArray) {

    $myArray[] = 'apple';
    $myArray[] = 'banana';
    $myArray[] = 'coconut';

    return $myArray;
}  

addItemsToMyArray($myArray);

echo count($myArray);    /* Gives 0 */
```

Why does `count($myArray)` give `0` instead of `3`?

Comment: You need to write  
`function addItemsToMyArray(&$myArray)`

Comment: or make use of the returned value: `$myArray = addItemsToMyArray($myArray);`

Comment: Because the parameter of your function is local to your function and don't modify the outer scope of your function. If you add `&`, it tells PHP to write into $myArray globally, not locally. That's how I understand it anyway. Maybe someone can give a more detailled answer? Or more correct?

Edit: @AlexBlex is right also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `addItemsToMyArray()` has correctly been set up to return the array to the main PHP code but you forgot to catch that return value and put it in a variable. One way to write this code and make the difference easier to see could be like this:

```
function addItemsToMyArray($tmpArray) {

    $tmpArray[] = 'apple';
    $tmpArray[] = 'banana';
    $tmpArray[] = 'coconut';

    return $tmpArray;
}  

$myArray = array();
$myArray = addItemsToMyArray($myArray);

echo count($myArray);    /* Gives 3 */
```

The variable used inside the function is a different variable than the `$myArray` variable outside of the function.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you, @Tweek, for the clear explanation. I see that the difference between javascript and PHP in this situation is that because PHP passes variables to functions _by value_ (not _by reference_) , the line `$myArray = addItemsToMyArray($myArray);` **_must be explicitly stated_** if the value of `$myArray` is to update.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specify otherwise, function/method arguments are pass-by-value, meaning you get a *copy* of them inside the function. If you want the function to change the variable that was passed to it, you need to pass-by-reference. As described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the
> value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get
> changed outside of the function). To allow a function to modify its
> arguments, they must be passed by reference.
>
> To have an argument to a function always passed by reference, prepend
> an ampersand (&) to the argument name in the function definition:

Note the ampersand before `$array` in the doc page for sorting functions like [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) and [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php):

> bool asort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
>
> bool ksort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )

Comment: This is a clear explanation, helping me to better understand the underlying mechanics in PHP - thank you @AlexHowansky. Would it then be correct to say that in `function myFunction(myVariable)` in Javascript, `myVariable` is _passed by reference_ whereas in `function My_Function($My_Variable)` in PHP, `$My_Variable` is _passed by value_?

Comment: I believe JS is pass-by-reference for objects and pass-by-value for everything else.